# How to encrypt my password in phpMyAdmin for my own cms website

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I am creating a login system for my own website so I can update it via a form.  I have manually added myself to a table in the database I called users, although there will only ever be me, and I added my password plain text.  However, I have since being reading about hashing passwords, but from what I can see this is only done from a php function, can I do it in phpMyAdmin using just the sql section?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you edit the structure of your table, there should be a column called "Function". 
There you can select MD5, and any value stored in that Field will become hashed. So if you already have a password stored in your table, it will become hashed aswell.

Like this: http://www.xodino.it/wp-content/uploads/file/ubuntuftp/pureftpd-02.png

Comment: thanks, but I don't seem to have a function column, see my image I added to my question

Comment: It worked, I realised it wasn't editing the type of the field but choosing the function when inserting a new row

Comment: does it return the correct value when you are comparing it with a user inputted value in a php page, i.e. it converts it to the actual password?

Comment: no, you can never return it back to the original, and you shouldn't for security reasons. If you want to compare them, you can do `md5($_POST['normalPasword']) == $hashedPaswordFromDatabase;`         That way, you're comparing the 2 hashed passwords.

Comment: ahh I see, so it uses the same function to check it against it, so I'd do: $password=md5($_POST['mypassword']);

$query = "SELECT *
        FROM users
        WHERE username = '$username'
   and password='$password'";

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-hashing.html

But if you want to do it with PHP take a look here. That's a good article about password hashing:
http://phpsec.org/articles/2005/password-hashing.html

Answer (score 1):

You should salt your password and then hash it. Passwords that use MD5 or SHA1 are no longer secure - you should generate a unique salt for each password and use Bcrypt to create a strong hash.

This article gives a decent explanation:
[http://www.bentasker.co.uk/blog/security...](http://www.bentasker.co.uk/blog/security/201-why-you-should-be-asking-how-your-passwords-are-stored)
But doing a Google search yourself will gives you lots of results on storing passwords in databases.

You can change the Type to BINARY and give it a length of 60. If your application will remain private, using the MD5, SHA1, or the PASSWORD function is okay. A description of the encryption and compression functions are available in the official MySQL docs here: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

May I know what you want here? You want to use SQL to  encrypt your passwords? So, before saving the password, you call something like this?

```
select * from user where username='me' and password=md5($mypass)
```

If that is what you want, it depends on your SQL engine. MySQL has a function called MD5 to help you do the job.

Comment: well I want to insert my password as encrypted into the database but be able to retrieve it again using sql in a php script.  I am only every going to have one user (me) so there is no point creating a register form, which is why I want to do it directly in phpMyAdmin with mySQl

Comment: You store the MD5 checksum in your database, and MD5 is one way encryption. (so you cannot get back what the message was).
When you want to verify your log in you can always do something similar to 
Select * from user where username='myname' and password=md5('mypass')

But if you want to store your password in database and recover the original text, you need to use some other encryption algo, and you may also need to remember the private key somewhere...
Please see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest is to edit your table,there should be a column called "Function". There you can select MD5 from a drop down list and then click GO, and any value stored in that Field will become hashed. So if you already have a password stored in your table, However if you try to change again the converted hashed text to CHAR, it will change the original password and putting the right password on the php side will fail

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Desarrollo.Login SET password = md5('mypassword') WHERE Login.id = 1;
```

I think this can help.